# Where do I put business logic when I'm using the repository pattern?

Tags: repository-pattern

I am using the Repository Pattern for my application. I have a class User. User is identified by Email. The UserRepository contains a method CreateUser(User user). There is a business rule saying that users should have a unique Email.

I want to implement a transaction which first checks whether an email is in use and if not, the user is created. **Where should I put this code which is responsible for checking the uniqueness of the Email?**

This is definitely a business rule; it is business logic.  I think it is not correct to put this check in my UserRepository implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sort of thing typically goes in either (1) a service or (2) directly into the schema as a database constraint (and frequently both).

Using a service, you don't access the Repository directly from client code; you call a service which does the useful operations for you.

For example, something like:

```
public class UserService : ... {
  private Repository<User> _userRepository;

  public void CreateUser(User u) {
    // Verify that the user's email is unique.
    if ( ... ) {
      _userRepository.Create(u);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're building an application large enough to warrent a [repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) then you'll want to put this validation as close to the data as possible, probably a database constraint such as a unique index/key. This prevents situations of bugs leaking into code later due to corrupt data.

Comment: +1 absolutely - put it in the database - do never rely on the app to do too much validation....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a database for storage, you should definitely add a unique constraint on the e-mail column in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this excellent article on Simple Talk:

[Five Simple Database Design Errors You Should Avoid](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/)

See in Section 4:

> Enforcing Integrity via applications
>
> Proponents of application based
>   integrity usually argues that
>   constraints negatively impact data
>   access. They also assume selectively
>   applying rules based on the needs of
>   the application is the best route to
>   take. .....
>
> **The solution is simple.**
>
> **Rely on nothing else to provide**
>   **completeness and correctness except**
>   **the database itself.** By nothing, I
>   mean neither users nor applications
>   external to the database.**

So in your case - a unique constraint on your e-mail column should really be modelled in the database. That's the best place to put that piece of business logic, and will save you from a lot of grief in the long run.

Marc